# Wagtail image upload : how to set where the image is stored?

Tags: image, wagtail

Im discovering wagtail. When I create a post, i can upload images, but they are stored in the directory /media of my webapp.

I would like to store them in a s3 bucket or in the wagtail database.

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel 
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet 
from taggit.models import Tag as TaggitTag
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey 
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (FieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
    StreamFieldPanel,
)
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField 
from .blocks import BodyBlock
class BlogPage(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("description", classname="full")]
class PostPage(Page):
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
    "wagtailimages.Image", null=True,
    blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="+",)
    body = StreamField(BodyBlock(), blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blog.PostPageTag", blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [ ImageChooserPanel("header_image"), InlinePanel("categories", label="category"), FieldPanel("tags"),StreamFieldPanel("body"),]
    
@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=80)
    panels = [  FieldPanel("name"),
                FieldPanel("slug"),]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category" 
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag): 
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    
class PostPageBlogCategory(models.Model): 
    page = ParentalKey("blog.PostPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories" )
    blog_category = models.ForeignKey("blog.BlogCategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_pages")
    panels = [ SnippetChooserPanel("blog_category"),]
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("page", "blog_category")

class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("PostPage", related_name="post_tags")
```

In my settings.py I also have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR / 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

which correspond to the media folder in my webapp. I suppose I can tweak this but how do I put all the s3 authorization in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does what you are looking to do.

There is an [Amazon S3](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) section that walks through the setup process.

Comment: thanks, that helped a lot, but im still having issues cf here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72405680/zappa-wagtail-how-to-use-s3-for-media-images-server-error-500