# zappa wagtail how to use s3 for media/images (server error 500)

Tags: image, wagtail, zappa

Im using wagtail on an aws lambda with zappa.

Everything is working fine except the images i'm trying to upload in the blog posts.
That is to say when i try to upload an image in the /cms-admin in the images menu i get a server error 500 message.

I have configured the images to be stored on s3 following this post https://wagtail.org/blog/amazon-s3-for-media-files/ but it seems there is a problem.

Here is my models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel 
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet 
from taggit.models import Tag as TaggitTag
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey 
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from modelcluster.tags import ClusterTaggableManager
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (FieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
    StreamFieldPanel,
)
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField 
from .blocks import BodyBlock
class BlogPage(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("description", classname="full")]
class PostPage(Page):
    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
    "wagtailimages.Image", null=True,
    blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="+",)
    body = StreamField(BodyBlock(), blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blog.PostPageTag", blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [ ImageChooserPanel("header_image"), InlinePanel("categories", label="category"), FieldPanel("tags"),StreamFieldPanel("body"),]
    
@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=80)
    panels = [  FieldPanel("name"),
                FieldPanel("slug"),]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category" 
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

@register_snippet
class Tag(TaggitTag): 
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    
class PostPageBlogCategory(models.Model): 
    page = ParentalKey("blog.PostPage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="categories" )
    blog_category = models.ForeignKey("blog.BlogCategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_pages")
    panels = [ SnippetChooserPanel("blog_category"),]
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("page", "blog_category")

class PostPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey("PostPage", related_name="post_tags")
```

Here is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for react_wagtail_app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-jvstu05lh1fp2ow26blj&5%x_7bb(e*qt#(urj+$(2n&1i&)ka'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xwovkgc3f6.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.admin', 
'django.contrib.auth', 
'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
'django.contrib.sessions', 
'django.contrib.messages', 
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
"wagtail.contrib.forms", 
"wagtail.contrib.redirects", 
"wagtail.embeds", 
"wagtail.sites", 
"wagtail.users", 
"wagtail.snippets", 
"wagtail.documents", 
"wagtail.images", 
"wagtail.search", 
"wagtail.admin", 
"wagtail.core", 
"modelcluster",
"taggit", 
"blog",
"storages"]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'react_wagtail_app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'react_wagtail_app.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'spa', 
        'USER': 'postgres', 
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '146.190.238.8', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-FR'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "zappa-pasvx3uig"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'secret'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
#MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = "/dev/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX = "/static/"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
#MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR / 'media') 
WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = 'My Project'
```

I have seen in other posts here: [Configuring Django/Wagtail media to use S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235565/configuring-django-wagtail-media-to-use-s3)
that a special class is used inherited from S3BotoStorage. I was wondering if i didnt need to use that in my models.py for the Images?

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

Could you help me understand what is not properly configured so the images are properly uploaded to s3 and print on the screen normally

I ve tried to set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL='public-read' following another stackoverflow post but it is the same.

zappa tail gives me the following error :
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.

I ve managed to overcome this error by providing two separate credentials
AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
but i'm still having problems with the images

I'm considering giving up on aws lambda with zappa and switching to a container service

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't know anything about Zappa. We use ElasticContainerService running on EC2 instances we manage. We are considering going to ECS on Fargate but have not made the transition yet.

Looking at your settings file CHANGE YOUR AWS CREDENTIALS AT ONCE!!!!

After that, I am fairly sure you need the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings. Ours are set to MEDIA_ROOT = '/media' and MEDIA_URL = '/media/'. And we do have AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read' so that images can be served straight from S3 using the default for WAGTAILDOCS_SERVE_METHOD of 'redirect'

Until you get  s3 storage working, I would remove the AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN setting so you can debug one thing at a time.